# Django models.py (API result) - retrieve current post to add api result

Tags: django

I'm new to Django I got an issue. I don't know how to retrieve the current post inside of models.py. I've tried different way for that.

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'aliments'
```

or no error and no add to Post from ListAliments

```
get_object_or_404(Post, id=kwargs['id'])
```

here is my models.py

```
class ListAliments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)     
    
    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = unique_slugify(self, slugify(self.name))
        super(ListAliments, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    url_image = models.URLField(max_length=200, default=None)
    aliments = models.ManyToManyField('ListAliments',blank=True, related_name='listaliments_post')
    
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = unique_slugify(self, slugify(self.title))
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs) -> First save for Post which has not no ID
    ...
    if self.url_image:
        request = ...
        response = ...
        
        if response:
            names = []
            for concept in response.outputs[0].data.concepts:
                current_aliments = ListAliments.objects.filter(name=concept.name)
                    current_post = Post.objects.filter(url_image=self.url_image) #get_object_or_404(Post, id=kwargs['id']) 
                    if current_aliments.count()<1:
                        create_aliments = self.aliments.create(name=concept.name)
                        current_post.aliments.add(create_aliments)
                    else:
                        existed_aliments = ListAliments.objects.get(name=concept.name)
                        current_post.aliments.add(existed_aliments)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Post.objects.filter(url_image=self.url_image)` returns `QuerySet`
in order to get object call `first` so `Post.objects.filter(url_image=self.url_image).first()`; note that you can get `None`

Comment: Thanks Pawel :) do you have any idea to make it working because with Post.objects.filter(url_image=self.url_image).first() no name from ListAliments are added to Post